# Uppercase whole \newenvironment

Tags: fonts, environments

I am trying to uppercase a whole new environment without success with the code below :

```
\newenvironment{upc}{
   \MakeUppercase\bgroup
}
{
   \egroup
}
```

Here is an example :

```
\begin{upc}
    23 Harrogate Dr. Foo, PA 17036 \\
    717.576.----- \quad Me@foo.com
\end{upc}
```

But the case doesnt change.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you show an example of proposed usage? I'm not sure an environment is the right tool. Are you planning to have paragraph breaks in the environment?

Comment: Thank you. See my edited post. And yes, i need to use linebreak in it. When i changed it with \newcommand i had an error on the linebreak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Package `environ` allows the capture of the environment body in a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{upc}{\MakeUppercase{\BODY}}

\begin{document}
\begin{upc}
  \noindent
  23 Harrogate Dr. Foo, PA 17036 \\
  717.576.--- \quad Me@foo.com
\end{upc}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A centered version. After `\centering`, the macro `\\` is no longer robust and needs to be prefixed by `\protect`. The following example goes without by making `\\` robust via `\robustify` of package `etoolbox`.

Also the closing `\par` is important, because TeX uses the settings by `\centering` at the end of the paragraph. If the paragraph end is after the environment, the settings of `\centering` are lost and the previous settings are used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\NewEnviron{upc}{%
  \par
  \centering
  \robustify\\%
  \MakeUppercase{\BODY}%
  \par
}

\begin{document}
\begin{upc}
  23 Harrogate Dr. Foo, PA 17036 \\
  717.576.---\quad Me@foo.com
\end{upc}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Centered result]

Comment: Really nice, so it's not possible to uppercase an environment without extra package ?

Comment: @CharlesFollet Feel free to study the package code and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I just wanted to understand why the MakeUppercase doesn't work. But I mark it so you get your rep points

Comment: Can you try \NewEnviron{upc}{\centering\MakeUppercase{\BODY}} ? i got an error.  (! Use of \@icentercr doesn't match its definition.)

Comment: @CharlesFollet See updated answer.

Comment: @CharlesFollet: `\MakeUppercase` is a macro with one parameter, so you need _explicit_ braces around its argument, not simply  `\bgroup`…`\egroup`.  (I’m saying this just because you asked.)